# Scene Text Detection in Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

In the new release of OpenCV (3.0), there is a module to detect texts in a camera image as shown in [this page](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/objdetect/doc/erfilter.html). However, the link to the demonstration codes to illustrate this module (https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/textdetection.cpp)is broken. Any idea on how to use this module? Thanks.

Comment: [things are moving](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/commit/1ad9827fc4ede1b9c42515569fcc5d8d1106a4ea)

Comment: technically, version 3 of opencv hasn't been released (2.4.9 at the moment), and 3 is still in development. As with any other code in development, you'll find lots of other things that may be broken too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can google "blob/master/samples/cpp/textdetection.cpp" and you'll find some forks. [Example](https://github.com/Balaje/opencv-1/blob/master/samples/cpp/textdetection.cpp). 
EDIT:
They have moved the whole text detection / recognition thing here! :)
http://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/text